# Envfit show incomplete taxa names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot Envfit on NMDS plot of my data, but the plot dosen't show the complete names of my taxa.

I've already tried to minimize the size of text but it dosen't work.

Any idea on how to resolve this problem ?

Here's my script:

```
p<-ggplot()
p<-p+geom_point(data=df,aes(NMDS1,NMDS2,colour=Type, shape=Soil))
#Draw taxas
p<-p+geom_segment(data=df_biofit, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = NMDS1, yend = NMDS2),
                  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),color="#808080",alpha=0.5)

p<-p+geom_text(data=as.data.frame(df_biofit*1.1),aes(NMDS1, NMDS2, label = rownames(df_biofit)),color="#808080",alpha=0.5, size=3)
#Draw environmental variables
p<-p+geom_segment(data=df_envfit, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = NMDS1, yend = NMDS2),
                  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),color="#4C005C",alpha=0.5)

p<-p+geom_text(data=as.data.frame(df_envfit*1.1),aes(NMDS1, NMDS2, label = rownames(df_envfit)),color="#4C005C",alpha=0.5)
p<-p+theme_bw()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKIEJ.png)

Comment: Have you tried `+ coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`?

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand ! I've tried it as you suggested. It lets the text appear even if it's outside the grey plot which is good, but it removes the arrows. Any idea on how to make it keeps them?